# Twiio resend SMS (within short intervals) - What is the expected behaviour

Tags: error-handling, twilio, sms, twilio-api, one-time-password

I am using an *Identity and Access Management*(IAM) vendor who provide a *Multi-Factor Authentication* (MFA) Service (using SMS and other channels). They use *Twilio* as their SMS service provider and what I see currently is a behaviour (described in the scenario below) from my IAM provider which is strange and wondering what the underlying Twilio API's behavior is.

I am unable to see this info from the Twilio API docs hence seeking assistance.

Scenario:

1. Customer uses IAM to login and my IAM provider using Twilio sends a OTP
2. The OTP comes through but in my test case, I trigger the resend OTP process

In both the steps, I get the right message (the template and senderID that we have configured in the IAM tool)

3. If I now trigger the OTP resend process a second time (3rd OTP in total for the same number), we receive a message which has AUTHMSG as the senderid and uses a default template message (which is different from what we have configured).

I am working with my IAM vendor to understand what is happening here and I am trying to see if Twilio is playing a part in this (trying to do some smarts as they think that there is some SMS delivery issue - which is the message I am in a way communicating by hitting the resend OTP multiple times)

Is AUTHMSG a senderID that is owned by Twilio? I don't believe so but I am trying to better understand this space.

SenderID is a construct that varies from country to country. Some Contries mandate that users register it with the local regulators while in other countries there is no explicit registration process.

I am worried that if my customers receive this message, they are going to be confused and suspect a Spam/Phishing kind of an activity.

I attempted a similar exercise with PayPal and they were consistent in their SMS OTP Resend. The message was always the same.  Unlike my IAM provider, PayPal sends OTP from multiple mobile numbers. In my tests I observed them sending OTPs from two distinct mobile numbers.

Would be glad if someone could assist and provide info in this space.

I will continue to work with my IAM provider and their support channel to see what is happening here.

[image: SMS received by the customers. Notice that we get the AUTHMSG prefix in some retry attempts]

Answer (score 1):

When using [Twilio Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) in a country that supports alphanumeric sender IDs, Twilio uses the `AUTHMSG` sender ID and registers it with countries around the world that require this, to ensure the best deliverability of OTP messages.

I think you will need to work with your IAM provider, and work out how they have implemented sending OTP messages to see what is going on here. If it is unclear, then you or the IAM provider may also have to contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: I did some reading on the Twilio APIs and noticed that Templates (https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/templates) is possibly something that I believe my IAM provider is using. I will chase it up with them. I also observed that this is currently in Beta status. The country in question here is Australia which supports Alphanumeric SenderIDs.

Comment: I am also intrigued about the AUTHMSG prefix in the text (Refer to pictures in the original question).  This is not always present. Wondering if Twilio adds this prefix to the message (in certain instances/scenarios)?

Comment: Twilio does not, to my knowledge, prefix messages with the text "AUTHMSG". The messages that are being sent do not imply that the service is using Twilio Verify. It's hard to know what is going on without more detail from your IAM provider and how they are using Twilio to achieve this.

Comment: still chasing my vendor to get the details on how they use the Twilio API. will update the thread once i get the info from them.

Comment: Got this response from my IAM Vendor :
"Yes, we use Twilio Verify APIs as a fallback mechanism to send out SMS-based OTPs.

We use Twilio Verify's templates.

The templates and the delivery methods are fully handled by Twilio when using Twilio Verify."

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like they aren't using Twilio for the initial SMS messages, but eventually fallback to Twilio Verify which is when you get the message from `AUTHMSG`. This all seems down to the IAM vendor's implementation and you're going to need to work out what is acceptable with them.

Comment: Additional response from my IAM vendor: 
"We have Twilio and Twilio Verify to deliver OTP SMS.
Twilio will use your custom notification templates.
Twilio Verify will not allow custom templates.
We are going to remove Twilio Verify.
Twilio will still be used to deliver custom OTP SMS.". 
I have asked them what is the actual Twilio API that they use. Still waiting for a response

Comment: I assume they mean Twilio Messaging and Twilio Verify. And they fall back to Twilio Verify because they haven't got templates setup, so you get the default Verify message, but Verify is better optimised to deliver OTP messages. You can point them to the (currently private beta) [Verify Templates API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/templates) for something they can use so they can always use Verify but allow you to create template messages too.